# Realtime application - asp.net alternative to node.js and socket.io

Tags: asp.net, node.js, socket.io

I work with asp.net.

I want to write realtime application without ajax  polling.

I need free technology - something like node.js and socket.io.

What is the alternative for asp.net - NODE.JS and SOCKET.IO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)

> Async signaling library for .NET to help build real-time, multi-user
>   interactive web applications

- [Asynchronous scalable web applications with real-time persistent long-running connections with SignalR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx)
- [Learn how to use SignalR and Knockout in an ASP.NET MVC 3 web application to handle real-time UX updates.](http://iwantmymvc.com/mvc-3-signalr-knockout-real-time-notifications)
- [Fun with @SignalR](http://sumitmaitra.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/fun-with-signalr/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use httplistener/tcplistener? It's in the BCL and is a part of an ECMA standard. So, I guess you can say it is free? No?

Answer (score 0):

I've used AspComet in the past.

Source code: https://github.com/nmosafi/aspcomet

Overview: http://neilmosafi.blogspot.com/2010/11/aspcomet-high-level-architecture.html